# Haskell type declaration using arrow operator

Tags: haskell

I encountered a Haskell type declaration using arrow operator like the following :

```
type Acceleration = State -> Vec
```

But how can that be ? coz I've never encountered such use before (in learning Haskell tutorials).

if the declaration is a-OK then what its definition should look like ? 
How do I even use such a type ?

Comment: I'm not even sure where to begin answering this. This is a type synonym - there is no definition. Are you confusing this with a function signature perhaps?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That's a type synonym. It's expressing that an `Acceleration` is a function that goes from `State` to `Vec`.

Simplify a bit and imagine the set of functions that go from `Int` to `String`. Let's call them `Frobnicators`.

```
type Frobnicator = Int -> String
```

We can define such a function which we could then say has a type of `Frobnicator`.

```
foo :: Frobnicator
foo = show . (+3)
```

Comment: IC.. it kinda works like find-and-replace or preprocessor thing

Comment: @himekami if that's how you want to think of it. It's helpful in a broader sense to name things reasonably. `data Card = Card Rank Suit; type Hand = [Card]; type Deck = [Card]; shuffle :: RandomGen s => s -> Deck -> Deck` etc...